# C++ and GLUT smooth movement

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I am new at using graphics with C++ and I have the following code from this
[tutorial](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glut-tutorial/the-code-so-far/)

here is the code

```
#include <windows.h>
#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#else
#include <GL/glut.h>
#endif

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

float angle = 0.0f;
float lx = 0.0f, lz = -1.0f;
float x = 0.0f, z = 5.0f;

float deltaAngle = 0.0f;
float deltaMove = 0;

void drawSnowMan(){

    glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.75f, 0.0f);
    glutSolidSphere(0.75f, 20, 20);

    glTranslatef(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glutSolidSphere(0.25f, 20, 20);

    glPushMatrix();
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glTranslatef(0.5f, 0.10f, 0.18f);
    glutSolidSphere(0.05f, 10, 10);
    glTranslatef(-0.1f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glutSolidSphere(0.05f, 10, 10);
    glPopMatrix();

    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
    glutSolidCone(0.8f, 0.5f, 10, 2);

}

void changeSize(int w, int h){

    if(h == 0)
        h = 1;
    float ratio = 1.0*w/h;

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);

    glLoadIdentity();

    glViewport(0,0,w,h);

    gluPerspective(45.0f, ratio, 0.1f, 100.0f);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

}

void computePos(float deltaMove){
    x += deltaMove * lx * 0.1f;
    z += deltaMove * lz * 0.1f;
}

void computeDir(float deltaAngle){
    angle += deltaAngle;
    lx = sin(angle/75.0);
    lz = -cos(angle/75.0);
}

void pressKey(int key, int xx, int yy){
    switch(key){
    case GLUT_KEY_LEFT: deltaAngle = -0.5f; break;
    case GLUT_KEY_RIGHT: deltaAngle = 0.5; break;
    case GLUT_KEY_UP: deltaMove = 0.5f; break;
    case GLUT_KEY_DOWN: deltaMove = -0.5f; break;
    }
}

void relaseKey(int key, int x, int y){
    switch(key){
    case GLUT_KEY_LEFT:
    case GLUT_KEY_RIGHT: deltaAngle = 0.0f; break;
    case GLUT_KEY_UP:
    case GLUT_KEY_DOWN: deltaMove = 0; break;
    }
}

void renderScene(void){

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glLoadIdentity();

    if(deltaMove)
        computePos(deltaMove);
    if(deltaAngle)
        computeDir(deltaAngle);

    gluLookAt(  x, 1.0f, z,
                x+lx, 1.0f, z+lz,
                0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f
              );

    glColor3f(0.9f, 0.9f, 0.9f);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glVertex3f(-100.0f, 0.0f, -100.0f);
        glVertex3f(-100.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f);
        glVertex3f(100.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f);
        glVertex3f(100.0f, 0.0f, -100.0f);
    glEnd();

    angle += 0.1f;

    for(int i = -3; i < 3; i++){
        for(int j = -3; j < 3; j++){
            glPushMatrix();
            glTranslatef(i*10.0,0, j*10.0);
            drawSnowMan();
            glPopMatrix();
        }
    }
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitWindowSize(320,320);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);

    glutCreateWindow("Lighthouse 3D");

    glutDisplayFunc(renderScene);
    glutReshapeFunc(changeSize);

    glutIdleFunc(renderScene);

    glutSpecialFunc(pressKey);
    glutIgnoreKeyRepeat(1);
    glutSpecialUpFunc(relaseKey);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    glutMainLoop();

    return 1;
}
```

My problem is the following, when i try to turn to the left and i keep the left key pressed everything works perfectly fine. When i try to hit the left once the action is not smooth at all. In some cases if the button stroke is too fast it even turns to the opposite direction!

Comment: You are not querying the mouse buttons anywhere in your code, so I wonder how pressing the mouse does affect your application at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean **keyboard** instead of **mouse**, in which case to have a "smoother" and "slower" feel you need to adjust your `deltaAngle` values, which might be too high.

This is only a temporary fix, since those values may affect other machines in different ways - some may be faster, some may be slower. You need to calculate the host machine's FPS in your render loop and multiply your `delta` values with it, to have the same performance on every computer. This is called **time-based movement** and is an essential feature of every modern graphics application.

This is exactly what is happening in the following tutorial, when a dot is moving too fast on the screen.

http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson32/index.php

Comment: Yes i mean keyboard, sorry for that! Ok thanks, i will look into it, that seems a great tutorial! Also, i tried dividing and squaring the angle but it doesnt work, or it works in funny ways...

Answer (score 0):

- A `glutIdleFunc()` will eat all your battery/CPU/GPU, use a `glutTimerFunc()` instead to redraw on a predictable, *sane* schedule.
- Accumulate your input state between frames and apply it in your `glutTimerFunc()` instead of trying to do it right in your keyup/keydown callbacks.
- No need for a `glutResizeFunc()`, do all that just before your draw.
- You're using C++ so you should use the C++ versions of C headers, like `<cmath>` instead of `<math.h>`.

All together:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <map>

std::map< int, bool > keys;
void pressKey(int key, int xx, int yy)
{
    keys[ key ] = true;
}
void relaseKey(int key, int x, int y)
{
    keys[ key ] = false;
}

float angle = 0.0f;
float lx = 0.0f, lz = -1.0f;
float x = 0.0f, z = 5.0f;
void update()
{
    const float angleStep = 0.5f;
    if( keys[ GLUT_KEY_LEFT  ] )    angle -= angleStep;
    if( keys[ GLUT_KEY_RIGHT ] )    angle += angleStep;

    const float moveStep = 0.5f;
    float move = 0.0f;
    if( keys[ GLUT_KEY_DOWN  ] )    move -= moveStep;
    if( keys[ GLUT_KEY_UP    ] )    move += moveStep;

    x += move * lx * 0.1f;
    z += move * lz * 0.1f;

    lx = sin(angle/75.0);
    lz = -cos(angle/75.0);
}

void drawSnowMan()
{
    glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.75f, 0.0f);
    glutSolidSphere(0.75f, 20, 20);

    glTranslatef(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glutSolidSphere(0.25f, 20, 20);

    glPushMatrix();
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glTranslatef(0.5f, 0.10f, 0.18f);
    glutSolidSphere(0.05f, 10, 10);
    glTranslatef(-0.1f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glutSolidSphere(0.05f, 10, 10);
    glPopMatrix();

    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
    glutSolidCone(0.8f, 0.5f, 10, 2);
}

void renderScene(void)
{
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    const double w = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH );
    const double h = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT );
    gluPerspective(45.0f, w / h, 0.1f, 100.0f);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    gluLookAt
        (
        x, 1.0f, z,
        x+lx, 1.0f, z+lz,
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f
        );

    glColor3f(0.9f, 0.9f, 0.9f);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex3f(-100.0f, 0.0f, -100.0f);
    glVertex3f(-100.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f);
    glVertex3f(100.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f);
    glVertex3f(100.0f, 0.0f, -100.0f);
    glEnd();

    for(int i = -3; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for(int j = -3; j < 3; j++)
        {
            glPushMatrix();
            glTranslatef(i*10.0,0, j*10.0);
            drawSnowMan();
            glPopMatrix();
        }
    }

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void timer( int value )
{
    update();
    glutTimerFunc( 16, timer, 0 );
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitWindowSize(320,320);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);

    glutCreateWindow("Lighthouse 3D");

    glutDisplayFunc(renderScene);
    glutSpecialFunc(pressKey);
    glutSpecialUpFunc(relaseKey);
    glutTimerFunc( 0, timer, 0 );

    glutMainLoop();

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Fixing the rendering to a specific delay is not the best idea. Assume we have a 60Hz (=16.66ms per Frame) Monitor, and we have a fixed render rate of 16Hz we will constantly miss vsync events and display frames twice or never. This gets more terrible when haven a 120Hz Monitor, because this solution only provides a new image for approximately every 2nd vsync.